# Oneliner for multiline regex s/,\n]/]/g?

Tags: vim, shell, script, sed, awk

Can someone provide a simple one-liner to remove certain line breaks?

In **vim** I use `%s/,\n]/]/g`

This should be possible with a very simple one-liner IMHO, but how?

Comment: First remove newlines, then use sed.

    tr -d '\r\n' | sed -e "s/,\n\]/\]/g"

But now everything is on one long line ?

Comment: "Certain linebreaks"? Which ones?

Comment: those that occur in the pattern, i.e. surrounded by , and ]

Comment: I can post an answer using Perl if you're interested.

Comment: yes, pls, anything is appreciated, though perl is not at all my favourite ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
perl -e "$_ = join('', <>); s/,\n]/,]/g; print;" < input_file > output_file
```

Comment: aii, that's a long one-liner, the actual vim command is so simple ...

Comment: Who cares? It works... The problem actually is the file input (<>). I have to convert the resulting array read from the file to a single line to process (*$_ = join('', <>);*) because file is splitted precisely by "\n". If anyone knows how to read a file in one single scalar, I'd be glad to modify it into something shorter.

Comment: *** If anyone knows how to read a file in one single scalar
local $/ = undef;$string = <FILE>;

Comment: I learned it in the meantime, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/,\n]/]/g' file
```

or this:

```
sed 'N;s/,\n]/]/;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

## multiline replace for all *.c files

`perl -p -i.bak -e 's#to_find\n\n#to_replace#g' *.c`